# Node.js + TSV formatting

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node application i am running a query and getting the results. I have to format the result into my required way....

Consider my result from query look like this:

```
[ { id_0: 356,
    name_0: 'xxxxx',
    id_1: 33,
    name_1: null,
    id_2: 602,
    name_2: 'yyyyyyy',
    collecteddate: '31/03/2011',
    value: '{"value1": "0.92", "value2": "3728104", "value3": "43", "value4": "0.66", "value5": "1050", "value6": "0.20"' },
  { id_0: 356,
    name_0: 'xxxx',
    id_1: 33,
    name_1: null,
    id_2: 603,
    name_2: 'yyyyyyyyyyy',
    collecteddate: '31/03/2011',
    value: '{"value1": "inf", "value2": "4646732", "value3": "100", "value4": "0.88", "value5": "26705", "value6": "-1.61"']
```

From this i have to format to tsv.

So i am using the following code:

```
sequelize.query(query).success(function(results) {
                        results.forEach(function(elem, i){
                            var keys = [];
                            var values = [];
                            var value = results[i].value;
                            value = JSON.parse(value);
                            for(var prop in value){
                                keys.push(prop);
                                values.push(value[prop]);
                                }                                   
                                results[i].value = values;
                                results[i].key = keys;
                        })
                        results = tsv.stringify(results);
```

By using the above code i am getting output as:

```
id_0         name_0      id_1         name_1    value                  key
356          xxxxxx      33            yyyy     0.6,3455,3.5,45.0    value1,value2,value3
```

But i need output as:

```
id_0         name_0      id_1         name_1    value                  key
356          xxxxxx      33            yyyy     0.6                   value1
356          xxxxxx      33            yyyy     3455                  value2
etc....
```

How can i achieve this.If needed i am ready to give additional details.Help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an object for every value and put it in a new array:

```
var newResults = [];

results.forEach(function(elem, i){
    var value = JSON.parse(elem.value);

    function createObj(key, value) {
        var obj = {};
        for(var k in elem) {
            obj[k] = elem[k];
        }
        // add key
        obj.key = key;

        // overwrite value
        obj.value = value;

        return obj;
    }

    // loop through the values
    for(var prop in value){
        newResults.push(createObj(prop, value[prop]));
    }
});

results = tsv.stringify(newResults);
```

Here is the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aFFVE/3/)**

Comment: Thanks @friedi.. Can you please tell me where is the console in jsfiddle..i am searching for it..

Comment: I've forgot the key property and added it. You can reach the console by pushing the F12 key.

Comment: I've updated the jsFiddle. Now you can see the output in the html field.